# Freeze Top Child at top in flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have multiple flow layout panel in main flow layout panel.

I want to freeze the top panel in parent, so that while vertical scrolling the top panel resides at its position while other child panel will scroll.

just like the  header row in data grid.

How can i achieve this ??

Comment: It is not impossible, use the Scroll event to change the Location.  But the visual effect is very unpleasant, you can't reasonably expect the user to modify the system setting that does that.  Consider the simple workaround, instead of making the split panel scrollable add a panel that has the stuff that needs to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your control structure.
Instead of having all inner panels as direct children of the outer most flow layout panel, have only two direct children - your "header" flow layout panel, and another panel to act as a "body" and keep all other flow layout panels inside - then you can scroll only the "body" panel.

Here is a pseudo-xaml to help you visualize it:

```
<flowLayoutPanel> <!-- main -->
    <flowLayoutPanel> <!-- header -->
    </flowLayoutPanel>
    <flowLayoutPanel> <!-- body, this is the one you want to scroll -->
        <flowLayoutPanel> <!-- content -->
        </flowLayoutPanel>
        <flowLayoutPanel> <!-- content -->
        </flowLayoutPanel>
        <flowLayoutPanel> <!-- content -->
        </flowLayoutPanel>
    </flowLayoutPanel>
</flowLayoutPanel>
```

and an Image, if you prefer:

[image]